# How to convert to uint?

Tags: c#

I want to convert this to uint like this one converts to string?

```
Formation = comboBox2.SelectedItem == null ? "Any" : (comboBox2.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString(),
League = comboBox3.SelectedItem == null ? "Any" : (comboBox3.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem)
```

what to put, like `Value.toString()` to get the uint?

Comment: `comboBox3.SelectedItem` is `uint`?

Comment: You're using the ternary operator, where both possible return values have to be the same type. "Any" won't convert to UInt very well ;-)

Comment: @console: 1.Soner just asked if it's type is already `uint` 2.You are presuming that it is a `Nullable<uint>` but OP just added the question mark in the title because it is  a question :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several opportunities to do this.

1. `Convert.ToUInt32(INPUT);`
2. `uint.Parse(INPUT);`
3. `uint.TryParse(INPUT, out UINTVALUE);`

Try

```
uint uintValue = Convert.ToUInt32((comboBox2.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value);
```

Or you can try: (This may be saver)

```
uint parseResult;
if (uint.TryParse((comboBox2.SelectedItem as ComboboxItem).Value.ToString(), out parseResult))
{
   // Parsing successful
}
```

Comment: i've tried those but I can't put them at the end of that line without getting any errors. :(

Answer (score 0):

What about...

```
uint.Parse(comboBox3.Text);
```

However, how do you want to mix string and uint at all? Is `League` an `uint` property, what determines an undefined league, maybe 0?

```
League = comboBox3.Text== null ? 0 : uint.Parse(comboBox3.Text),
```